# DWORD division Delphi / C++

Tags: c++, delphi

So in C++ i can do something like:

```
DWORD count;

count = 3 / 1.699999;

cout << count;
```

which will result in:

> 1

Delphi however complains Cardinal and Extended mismatch.

```
var
  count: DWORD;
begin
  count := 3 / 1.6;
  Writeln(inttostr(count));
```

So i either have to round `count := round(3 / 1.6)` which results in:

> 2

or trunc `count := trunc(3 / 1.6)` which results in

> 1

Is trunc really the way to go?
Is there maybe a compiler switch i would have to toggle?

You would think it's easy to google something like that but trust me it isn't.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: We must have different Google then. First hit for *Delphi Cardinal and Extended mismatch* goes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21588915/960757). And that's not even the exact error message you got.

Comment: Thanks @TLama. So according to the documentation div is the way to go?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C/C++ only has one arithmetic division operator - `/` - but its behavior depends on the type of operands you pass to it.  It can perform both *integer division* and *floating point division*.

Delphi has two arithmetic division operations - `div` for *integer division*, and `/` for *floating point division*.

Your C++ code is performing *floating point division*, and then assigning the result to a `DWORD`, which is not a floating point type, so the assignment truncates off the decimal point:

`1 / 1.699999` is `1.764706920415836`, which truncates to `1`.

In Delphi, the `/` operator returns an `Extended`, which is a floating-point type.  Unlike C/C++, Delphi does not allow a floating-point type to be assigned directly to an integral type.  You have to use `Round()` or `Trunc()`.

In this case, the Delphi equivalent of your C++ code is to use `Trunc()`:

```
var
  count: DWORD;
begin
  count := Trunc(3 / 1.699999);
  Write(IntToStr(count));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to use `trunc(3 /1.699999).`.

Another way is to use a previous multiplication before the division.

```
var
  count: DWORD;
begin
  count := 3;
  count := (count*1000000) div 1699999;
  Writeln(inttostr(count));
```

Of course, to avoid overflow, `count` should be < `maxInt div 1000000`.

Comment: In general, this approach is not guaranteed to yield identical answers. Because 1.699999 is not exactly representable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "identical answers" to what? To floating point math? Yes, of course, this is as designed: here it uses integer math, so sometimes it is easier to work with, especially to avoid x87 slow transformations under Delphi 32 bit. I just wanted to show another way of doing divisions on integer values, precision safe (1699999 is exactly representable when applied to a 1000000 multiplier), with pure integer operations, and avoiding to work with floats. This is a known and used trick in a lot of implementation algorithms: do not use floats if you do not need them.