# Delphi: "Incompatible types Integer and Extended"

Tags: delphi, integer, delphi-7, pascal, incompatibletypeerror

I currently face the problem of not being able to divide my ClientWidth by 2 (or multiply with 0.5 because of the error message Delphi is giving me:

```
[Error] Unit1.pas(59): Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'
[Error] Unit1.pas(60): Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'
[Error] Unit1.pas(61): Incompatible types: 'Integer' and 'Extended'

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
 // responsive design
 with form1 do begin
 cmdFakultat.left:=0.5*ClientWidth-60;
 txtEingabe.left:=0.5*ClientWidth-60;
 lblAusgabe.left:=0.5*ClientWidth-60;
 end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588915/delphi-incompatible-types-integer-and-extended

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delphi: Incompatible types: 'integer' and 'extended'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588915/delphi-incompatible-types-integer-and-extended)

Comment: Well, it is possible duplicate of the example for the [user manual entry](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/E2010_Incompatible_types_-_%27%25s%27_and_%27%25s%27_(Delphi)) for this error message available in D7 thru F1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`Trunc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Trunc) or [`Round`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Round) functions, depending on your desired behavior, like this...

```
lblAusgabe.left := Trunc(0.5 * ClientWidth) - 60;
```

or

```
lblAusgabe.left := Round(0.5 * ClientWidth) - 60;
```

This cuts everything off after the decimal, leaving just an `Integer` type as a result.

As an alternative, you could also use [`div`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Arithmetic_Operators) to accomplish this, which is a bit more straight-forward and does this conversion for you...

```
lblAusgabe.left := (ClientWidth div 2) - 60;
```

Comment: Why Trunc rather than Round?

Comment: @David For the particular purpose of finding the "center" of something, I always use `Trunc` to always round down. That way, if I multiply by 2, it still fits within the bounds. Otherwise, if it had rounded up, and suppose you use this to calculate the width of two controls side by side, then one control would end up slightly off the visible client area. Therefore, I never use `Round` for this. But I added to my answer anyway. I only really use `Round` when it comes to money.

Comment: Your logic is wrong there Jerry. Round is better here. It minimises the error. If you round up and then multiply by two, the mistake is performing the arithmetic after rounding.

Comment: @David Okay, that's why I put in my answer "depending on your desired behavior". Believe me, I have my reasons, but just for you, just because you said something, I added `Round` too.

Comment: To get as close as possible to the centre you use round. No arguing about that. Fitting two control side by side then your approach won't fill the space. Can be one pixel short. Way to do that is to place the first control and set the second control's width to consume the remaining space. Then Trunc and round choice is arbitrary. But if you want to find the centre, then round minimises error.

Comment: Well, one could use Floor() just perfectly fine :-)

Comment: I should note if you use Round, it's important to keep the default banker's mode to prevent bias, as a division by 2 is either a whole number or an exact in-between (#.5).

Answer (score 0):

An integer can only contain whole numbers (I'm assuming lblAusgabe.left is an integer). The value you are trying to assign to it has a decimal point. Decimal point numbers can be stored in real, double or extended values in Pascal. To convert a number with a fraction to an integer you can round it using the round() function or you can discard the part after the decimal point using the trunc() function.

Another solution would be to calculate the value you need with integers. For example:

> cmdFakultat.left := ClientWidth div 2-60;

Div divides an integer and gives you back an integer value discarding anything behind the decimal point.